# Build Server and Windows 8 / RT Apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, build-process, build-automation, windows-rt

I've a windows 8 app and a windows 2012 Build Server with Jenkins and / or Finalbulder Contiua.

No I can only install Visual Studio for WinRT Apps only on Windows 8 or later.

So this means ,that my build server has to be windows  , right

is there a way to compule windows 8 apps on non windows 8 os ?

Is there some kind of "build win 8 sdk" for other os ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you'll need Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.

A Jenkins-specific tip: I tried a number of things but did not manage to have it start apps when Jenkins runs as a service. Starting from a logged-in user account was the only way I could get it to work.

Also I'd like to recommend our [Apprunner project](https://github.com/doo/metro-driver) which we developed to install, run and uninstall packages from within Jenkins.

Finally, if you're working on a Javascript-based app, you can have a look at [the unit-testing-related code](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT/tree/master/SQLite3JS) in our SQLite component which uses Jasmine and outputs JUnit/Jenkins-compatible test result files.